# OData without database but with Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api

I have an OData provider which doesn't use Entity Framework or any other sort of database.

I use the following 2 models:

```
public class ItemModel : TrackableBaseModel<Item>
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 ItemId { get; set; }

    public String ItemName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ItemSerialModel> ItemSerials { get; set; }
}


public class ItemSerialModel : TrackableBaseModel<ItemSerial>
{
    public Int32 ItemSerialId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Item")]
    public Int32? ItemId { get; set; }

    public ItemModel Item {get;set; }
}
```

But the OData $metadata shows:

```
<EntityType Name="ItemModel">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ItemId"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="ItemId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="ItemName" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <NavigationProperty Name="ItemSerials" Relationship="UserSite.Models.UserSite_Models_ItemModel_ItemSerials_UserSite_Models_ItemSerialModel_ItemSerialsPartner" ToRole="ItemSerials" FromRole="ItemSerialsPartner"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="ItemSerialModel">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ItemSerialId"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="ItemSerialId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="ItemId" Type="Edm.Int32"/>
    <NavigationProperty Name="ItemModel" Relationship="UserSite.Models.UserSite_Models_ItemSerialModel_ItemModel_UserSite_Models_ItemModel_ItemModelPartner" ToRole="ItemModel" FromRole="ItemModelPartner"/>
</EntityType>
```

But that doesn't make much sense, it comes with `ItemModelPartner` which doesn't even exist in the project.

How can I setup manual FK's so that the navigation properties will work in OData?

The WebApiConfig defines the models like this:

```
builder.EntitySet<ItemModel>("Items").EntityType.HasKey(x => x.ItemId);
builder.EntitySet<ItemSerialModel>("ItemSerials").EntityType.HasKey(x => x.ItemSerialId);
```

Comment: What's the reason for having the foreign key in addition to the `ItemModel.Item` property? Is it ever possible that `ItemSerialModel.Item.ItemId` does not equal `ItemSerialModel.ItemId`? If those two are always equal, I would think you wouldn't need `ItemSerialModel.ItemId` at all. What doesn't make sense about the generated $metadata? ItemModelPartner and ItemSerialsPartner are probably be auto-generated. They describe how entity sets are mapped to each other via this navigation property. I wouldn't worry too much about them unless you have multiple entity sets with the same type.

Comment: Well the problem is when I try to query from it, it throws the exception that the ItemPartner controller cannot be found... Which is odd because that doesn't even exist.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is this using ASP.Net Web API? I'm not very familiar with Web API myself so I'm not sure how the model actually gets created, but I think it'd be helpful to add that info (and the error message) to your question.

Comment: Well the model is created by hand :) As I said there is no underlaying provider, but it's done by hand all.

Comment: If you are using WebApi, can you please post your IEdmModel?

Comment: Where would I find the EdmModel?

Comment: Where are you defining your EdmModel? Are you using the ODataConventionModelBuilder? Most likely in a file named WebApiConfig?

Comment: Sorry I forgot about the EdmModel, it is created in the WebApiConfig, I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your EdmModel to as follows.

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder v1ODataConventionModelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

v1ODataConventionModelBuilder.EntitySet<ItemModel>("ItemModels");
v1ODataConventionModelBuilder.EntitySet<ItemSerials>("ItemSerials");

config.Routes.MapODataRoute("routename", "routeprefix/", v1ODataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel()
```

You should also be able to remove the following property

```
[ForeignKey("Item")]
public Int32? ItemId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion but didn't help. If I remove the ForeinKey attribute, how would OData know where the relations are?

Comment: OData doesn't really use ForeignKeys. Instead of thinking of the data model like a relational database (where related entities are joined via foreign keys), think of this like an object oriented data structure. If you want to create a relationship from class Bar to class Foo, you just need to have a property on Bar that has type Foo.

Comment: Ah ok I see I didn't know that. Unfortunately with the adjusted code it will comes up with the Partner in my $metadata, is this common behavior?

Comment: Yes. What I would suggest doing is using a program like LinqPad or any other OData metadata browser. That will give you a better representation of your edm.

Comment: You are right, I noticed now that the EDM / $metadata was correct but that the following step: connecting to JayData is not working properly with WebApi OData.

Comment: @JenS Hey Jen, like Rogier here, I would also have assumed the foreign keys were needed. I'm finding it hard to learn more about OData 4 modelling (in the absence of a database, all tutorials share the storage model, usually EF which makes it hard to work out what's needed for OData and what's for EF). Is there a good resource out there for OData modelling practices?

Answer (score 1):

For your ItemSerialModel, you should add "virtual" at the last line. Just like what you did in ItemModel.

```
public class ItemSerialModel : TrackableBaseModel<ItemSerial>
{
    public Int32 ItemSerialId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Item")]
    public Int32? ItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual ItemModel Item {get;set; }
 }
```

And as for Edm Model, you should do what Schandlich suggest. Hope this will help.

Comment: What does adding `virtual` do for OData?